# How get xml file located on sdcard and read the content? Android

Tags: android, xml, string, get, sd-card

I am having a problem, I need to read a xml file from my sdcard directory and save the contents at least, then to select de value between the xml tags, but if you can help me with the reading and conversion to a string it will already be very usefull.

file dir:
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/SCity/"+now //currentmillis
file name:
Notes.xml

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the xml using SAX or DOM parser.
follow these links:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-android/

Comment: Hum, in those sites teach how to work with xml from the web, what I am trying to do is from my sdcard, just need to know how get the contente of the file for one string.

Comment: use the path where your xml persists..rest is same

Answer (score -2):

Put your file in asset folder:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Load XML for parsing
            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                inputStream = assetManager.open("test.xml");
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }

            String s = readTextFile(inputStream);
            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tv.setText(s);
        }
    });
}

private String readTextFile(InputStream inputStream) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    try {
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
    return outputStream.toString();
  }
}
```